# Django: import error or possible settings misconfiguration

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a model I created in myapp/models.py in another file called store.py, but every attempt to import models.py has failed. Both store.py and model.py are in my Django app folder.

Here is what I tried so far:

A)

```
from . import models
radio = models.Radio(....)
```

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

B)

```
from myapp.models import Radio
radio = Radio(....)
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

C)

```
from .models import Radio
radio = Radio(....)
```

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

D)

```
from models import Radio
radio = Radio(....)
```

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Note:

- manage.py makemigrations && manage.py migrate have already been run after creating the model
- myapp is installed in settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS as 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'

My tree:

```
├── base
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── fetch.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── static
│   │   └── myapp
│   │       └── home.css
│   ├── store.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── myapp
│   │       └── home.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── output.txt
└── main.py
```

Comment: Are you attempting to run store.py as a stand-alone script? Django needs to be setup/configured before you can import models, a management command is the recommended way to add a script to your Django app https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: yes, but I also tried to run it through main.py with from myapp.store import store and had the same issue

Comment: You can do this in ur main.py:

`import os`
`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "base.settings")`

`import django`
`django.setup()`

`from myapp.store import store`


BUT, I don't recommend this, you should check out the link @IainShelvington sent for a better solution.
You can still do what I sent for testing stuff temporarily, but your server should just have one entry point, which is manage.py